# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on removeFromSuperview within singleton iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

I have a singleton that subclasses NSObject. It has a reference to an IntroView (subclass of UIView) which has been added to the root view controller as a subview. When a certain button is clicked on the view, it calls a method in the singleton which removes the view from its superview. I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2 every time. I have no idea why and I've tried using zombies and checking if the reference is nil. I've tried retaining it, everything (this is all using ARC). Here are some snippets of code:

```
//the property in the Manager.h file
@property (nonatomic, retain) IntroView *introView;

//Code called when that button is clicked and view is supposed to be removed
- (void)setOption:(NSString *)chosenOption {
    self.chosenOption = chosenOption;
    if (!!self.introView) {
        [self.introView removeFromSuperview]; //THIS LINE
}

//creates the singleton
+ (instancetype)manager {
    static Manager *manager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        manager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return manager;
}
```

Any and all ideas are appreciated!

I figured this out. There was a reference loop that ended up crashing the application.

Comment: What is `if (!!self.introView) {` suppose to do?

Comment: The !! is a common idiom to change an object to a BOOL value

Comment: How does the IntroView get added?  What does the stack trace look like when you crash?

Comment: Never saw it before.. Anyway, which boolean value is expected here, true or false? Is the property `self.introView` holding a reference to the view you want to remove and is IntroView a subclass of UIView? What if you change the retain attribute to weak?

Comment: Wow.. Looking at the stack it looks like that line of code is running something like 50 times... I just had a look at the method that calls that method from the IntroView (subclass of UIView) and its only getting called once.. Not really sure how that could be happening. Could it have something to do with the fact that Manager is a singleton?

Comment: At the very least you should set self.introview to nil, and as @MartinKoles said a weak property is probably more appropriate. And from a stylistic point of view, I prefer an explicit test for == nil - it is clearer what is happening and doesn't rely on obscure syntax (I didn't know what !! did either). It is the same work for the CPU and only marginally more typing

Comment: Where do you advise setting it to nil? After the removeFromSuperview? That would still throw the bad access... And I tried to make it weak, but that created other problems. Thanks for all your suggestions. Any other ideas?

Comment: Retain or strong reference should be used to indicate an owning relationship to the object. Your Manager class should not own your views, that is bad design. Instead, your viewController should own it. Setting the property above to weak will provide the necessary pointer to the view if you need to refer to it without changing its ownership. Also, I would suggest that the owning viewController should remove the IntroView from its superview rather then the Manager. Maybe this is where your issues are coming from. You have retain cycle and removing the IntroView breaks your code in other classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a reference loop. I had a function:

```
- (UIView *)introView
```

that referenced itself over and over.